# Mysterious event log message

Tags: event-log, spyware, bots

I saw this message in my event log today.  I tried searching on it without much success.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client" Guid="{1C95126E-7EEA-49A9-A3FE-A378B03DDB4D}" /> 
  <EventID>1014</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>1014</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000010000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-02-18T18:17:24.271060100Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>18114</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1176" ThreadID="1884" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>julies-cintiq</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-20" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="QueryName">p5-vobrhloz4uy4q-votne722p2jqolo3-128267-i2-bogus-dnssec-bd.gexperiments3.com</Data> 
  <Data Name="AddressLength">128</Data> 
  <Data Name="Address">02000000C0A80101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Friendly view:

Name resolution for the name `p5-vobrhloz4uy4q-votne722p2jqolo3-128267-i2-bogus-dnssec-bd.gexperiments3.com` timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.

I see that gexperiments3.com is registered to [MarkMonitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MarkMonitor) - a “brand protection” company?

I have no idea why my machine would be making calls to them.

Answer (score 0):

Like the name already suggests:

```
$ whois -h whois.markmonitor.com gexperiments3.com
Domain Name: gexperiments3.com
(...)
Registrant Organization: Google Inc.
Registrant Street: 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway,
Registrant City: Mountain View
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Postal Code: 94043
Registrant Country: US
(...)
```

Pretty much any website can trigger a DNS request.

This is perhaps a public study by Google on DNSSEC support in DNS servers / by ISPs.